# argument --subscription/-s/--name/-n: expected one argument

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-cli

I have **Variables.ps1** where all the variables initialized:

```
$RG="bicepRG"
$Subscription="subscription_id"
$location="eastus"
```

Azure CLI commands are in the different file of the same path:

```bash
az login --only-show-errors -o table --query Dummy
az account set -s $Subscription
```

`az login` command works fine (prompt for login > success result).
`az account set -s $Subscription` command giving me the error `argument --subscription/-s/--name/-n: expected one argument`

[image]

I'm at the same folder path (`C:\Users\hasher\source\repos\bicep>`) while running above Azure CLI Commands on Visual Studio Code.

I didn't find this error related solutions in the Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve myself, its solved. Posting the resolution which would help the community if anyone face similar issue in the future:

> argument --subscription/-s/--name/-n: expected one argument

I have been logged in to Azure Subscription using Azure CLI and it's been a long time so `az account set` command is unable to get the Subscription Id from the **`Variables.ps1`** file.

And Then I have initialized the **`Variables.ps1`** in the Visual studio Code terminal and then ran the commands `az login, az account set` (as given in the Question) --> Logged-in and Set the Subscription context successfully.